# Select max date and non identical records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to create query to select `MAX` date column record from identical records. I'm using this query but it returns identical records

```
SELECT DISTINCT SID, Id, MAX(ExpireDate) FROM tblPayers GROUP BY id,SID,ExpireDateEn
```

but the result I'm getting result is :

```
SID    Id    ExpireDate
2      3     5/25/2017
3      12    6/27/2017
1      13    5/28/2017
1      14    6/27/2017
```

Comment: please provide sample data, and expected result

Comment: @NetProjects lr,Specify your expected output.

Comment: the result is correct with your query, you don't need to group from ExpireDateEn, and there is no SID, and id     that possibly can group as your result,

Comment: `but it return identical record` where is in your output  identical record ?

Comment: Your query makes no sense. You group by ID, SID, and ExpireDateEn, which gives you one row per combination, e.g. one row for 2 - 3 - 5/25/2017. The maximum ExpireDateEn in that row is of course the ExpireDateEn itself: 5/25/2017. Then you even invoke `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows. How can there possibly be duplicates when all the columns you group by get selected?

Comment: Please answer Oto Shavadze's question. All rows are different from each other. So what do you consider a duplicate? Do you want one row per SID maybe? Then what ID do you want to show? The one of the record with the lastest date? Or must you even show an ID or would SID + MAX(ExpireDateEn) suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove ExpireDate from group by and also distinct from your query as that is also not required:-

```
Select distinct SID, id, ExpireDate
from tblPayers a
inner join
(
    select SID,MAX(ExpireDate) as dt 
    from tblPayers 
    group by SID
) b
on a.SID=b.SID and a.ExpireDate=b.dt
```

Comment: ty but it return 2 same SID i need to return just one max SID record

Comment: @NewProjects Ir check it again. I have updated the query as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment on an another answer (*"it return 2 same SID i need to return just one max SID record"*) I am guessing that you just want the latest record per SID, returning all other columns.

For this you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
SELECT  p.ID, 
        p.[SID], 
        p.[ExpireDate]
FROM    (   SELECT  p.ID, 
                    p.[SID], 
                    p.[ExpireDate],
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.[SID] 
                                                ORDER BY p.[ExpireDate] DESC)
            FROM    dbo.tblPayers AS p
        ) AS p
WHERE   p.RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with tablecte(sid,expiredate)
as
(
select SID , Max(ExpireDate)
    from tblPlayers 
    group by  SID
)
select tp.SID,tp.Id,tp.ExpireDate from tblPlayers tp join  tablecte tc
on tp.SID = tc.sid and tp.Expiredate = tc.expiredate
```

Comment: Please include more context/explanation for the code to make the answer more useful.